# PHP Curl Save Dynamic Image From VK

Tags: php, image, curl, save

I am trying to save an image from VK to a folder. However the image does not save correctly.

The code I use is:

```
// imageFromURL (Save an image from a URL)
function imageFromURL($url,$saveto){
    $ch = curl_init ($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
    $raw=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    if(file_exists($saveto)){
        unlink($saveto);
    }
    $fp = fopen($saveto,'x');
    fwrite($fp, $raw);
    fclose($fp);
}

imageFromURL('https://vk.com/captcha.php?sid=698254154192&s=1', 'Image/Captcha.png');
```

I think it must not be a standard image format? How could I save this and make sure it was a png format image with CURL?

Comment: when i run this, the image saves correctly into the Image folder.  i am then able to open and view it.  what is it that makes you think it's not saving?

Comment: That is odd, perhaps it's the php version or allowed settings that need changing maybe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exif_imagetype($image)` to return what type of image a file is.  PNG would return 3.

Additionally, you could check prior to saving:

```
$mime_type = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
```

and check for the mime type(s) you may be looking for. Mind you, there is some trust involved there because you're relying on the remote server to report that info correctly.

Comment: Is there any way to force a image header with CURL?

Comment: I modified my answer, hope that helps.